# Dealing with empty data points in Titanic Machine Learning train.csv

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

In the train.csv data in Titanic Machine Learning project, some passengers have their age data missing so the pandas module fills it in as 'NaN' and when feeding it into a sklearn algorithm it does not accept it. I tried dataset.fillna('') but now it turns into a empty string and not a float. Please send help.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
dataset = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
#dataset = dataset.fillna()
def preprocess(df):
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    processed_df = df.copy()
    le = LabelEncoder()
    done = le.fit_transform(processed_df)
    return done
survival = preprocess(dataset.Survived)

data = dataset.drop('Survived',axis= 1)
data = data.drop('PassengerId',axis=1)
data = data.drop('Embarked',axis = 1)
data = data.drop('Cabin',axis = 1)
data = data.drop('Fare',axis = 1)
data = data.drop('Ticket',axis = 1)
data = data.drop('Name',axis=1)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test= 
train_test_split(data,survival,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                         svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',C=0.1))
pipeline.fit(x_train,y_train)
print(accuracy_score(pipeline.predict(x_test),y_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

fillna replaces the Nan values with what you write so if you write '', it will be an empty string. just write:

```
 dataset.fillna(0)
```

if you need to distinguish between 0 and Nan, you can try replace it with -1, that's what we do.

Comment: But won't the algorithm take the 0 as a continuous value? I want the age to be empty, nothing. But the algorithm will accept it as a real data.

Comment: as much as i know, there is no way to give sklearn algorithms empty values. I had a situation were I got the scores on a test and than of course there is a difference between 0 score or Nan which means he didn't take the test. We tried two approaches for this problem: If the test score is a main feature than you can split the population into people who took the test and people who didn't. If like in my case it's a small feature than we handled it by giving it a different value than the rest as -1 and it worked fine but it might be different depending on your algorithm

Comment: another way is to replace the Nan with the columns average

Comment: @5Volts You need to impute the Nan values as Drza suggested. There are various techniques to do so. scikit-learn includes an [Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation-of-missing-values) or you can drop that column altogether. You need to test what works best for you here.

Answer (score 0):

there are many methods you can use to deal with the missing values in a machine learning project :

1. drop all the column with missing values
2. drop row containing missing values
3. Set the values to some value (zero, the mean, the median, etc.).

For the third option :

> Scikit-Learn provides a handy class to take care of missing values:
>   Imputer. Here is how to use it. First, you need to create an Imputer
>   instance, specifying that you want to replace each attribute’s missing
>   values with the median of that attribute:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(strategy="median") #or mean as you want 
x_train = imputer.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = imputer.fit_transform(x_test)
```

The result is a plain Numpy array containing the transformed features. If you want to put it back into a
Pandas DataFrame, it’s simple.

NB : You could also add the imputer in the pipeline just before the scaler .

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(Imputer(strategy="median"),
                         StandardScaler(),
                         svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',C=0.1))
```

Comment: StandardScaler will throw error with Nan values. Imputer should come first.

Comment: yes you are right  @VivekKumar , I just change the order and  edit my answer ; let me know how i can improve it